# Boost Build (bjam): Rerun test suite after success

Tags: boost, boost-build, bjam

How do I rerun a testsuite defined via the `run` directive in Boost Build?

Sample Jamroot file:

```
project test ;
exe a_runner : a.c ;
run a_runner : : : : a_run ;
```

Running it once works as expected:

```
caichinger@pc120:/tmp$ bjam -t a_run
...found 15 targets...
...updating 4 targets...
gcc.compile.c bin/gcc-4.6/debug/a.o
gcc.link bin/gcc-4.6/debug/a_runner
testing.capture-output bin/a_run.test/gcc-4.6/debug/a_run.run
**passed** bin/a_run.test/gcc-4.6/debug/a_run.test
...updated 4 targets...
```

But trying to run it again doesn't do anything:

```
caichinger@pc120:/tmp$ bjam -d2 -t a_run a_run
...found 15 targets...
caichinger@pc120:/tmp$
```

Relevant version numbers:
Boost.Build V2 (Milestone 12), Boost.Jam 03.1.19, Ubuntu Precise

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-a` [option](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/overview/invocation.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.options) to force rebuilding regardless of previous build status. For example:

```
b2 -d2 -a
```

Comment: That would rebuild the whole project, right? I just want to re-run a test tool that depends on external state, not rebuild everything (which takes ages).